# Reset Video.js plugin to initial state

Tags: video.js

I'm using jquery ui tabs and [video.js](http://www.videojs.com). I want to stop the video when I go to another tab and reset it when I come back to second tab.

Answer (score 7):

As of VideoJS v4.6 you can do the following to reset the player:

```
player.pause().currentTime(0).trigger('loadstart');
```

That `loadstart` is the key which shows the poster image and rebinds the first play event.

Answer (score 3):

u can use this for show poster or show bigplay button

```
$( '.backlink' ).click( function() {
                // Player (this) is initialized and ready.
            var myPlayer = _V_("video9");
            myPlayer.currentTime(0); // 2 minutes into the video            
            myPlayer.pause();
            myPlayer.posterImage.el.style.display = 'block';
            myPlayer.bigPlayButton.show();
        });
```

Answer (score 3):

It's even easier.

```
let player = Video(el);
player.on('ended', () => {
    player.initChildren();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need a reference to the video player.
http://videojs.com/docs/api/

```
var myPlayer = _V_("myVideoID");
```

Then you can use the API to start/stop/reset the video.

Stop:

```
myPlayer.pause();
```

Reset:

```
myPlayer.currentTime(0);
```

I'm not sure how the jquery tabs are set up, but you might be able to do:

```
$('.my-tab-class').click(function(){
  myPlayer.pause().currentTime(0);
});
```

Comment: Hi Heff, Thanks for your response. Its resetting the video at the first scene but its not showing poster image. I need to reset video at that level, it should be display the poster image with play button as it was at the first. How to do that?

Comment: if I would like to stop all videos if prev or next buttons are clicked , do I have to call every players ?

Answer (score 2):

```
player.reset();
```

Life is simple.

Comment: Mhh, After i call  `player.reset()` and set a new source the player shows only a black screen, without video.

Comment: If you enable bigPlayButton , you will see only the bigPlayButton and nothing else

Answer (score 1):

Get the id of the video.just append _html5_api with the id since videojs appends these letters and then you could use pause and make currentTime equal to 0.

```
var videoStop = document.getElementById(videoId+"_html5_api");
 videoStop.pause();     
 videoStop.currentTime= 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I found was using the videojs api, invoke the reset function followed by initChildren for reconstruct the player structure, i'm using vesion 5.10.7.

```
videojs('sublime_video', {}, function () {
    var videoPlayer = this;
    videoPlayer.width(screen.width / 2);
    videoPlayer.height(720);
    videoPlayer.on("ended", function(){
        videoPlayer.reset().initChildren();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a way to reintialize the VideoJS plugin then I found this :-

```
var player = videojs('my-player');
player.on('ended', function() {
  this.dispose();
});
```

Just dispose off the video and init again.

Source:- https://docs.videojs.com/tutorial-player-workflows.html#dispose

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but this post appeared on top of google search, you can do:

```
player.src(player.src());
```