# onscroll load video at first with poster video.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, video

I am using video.js, [here is my **DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/gepME/104/)

```
<video class="video-js vjs-default-skin" src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" controls="true" preload="yes"  poster="http://www.videojs.com/img/poster.jpg" data-setup="{}">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>
```

When I click on play button video starts to play, it is ok works how it should, but when I scroll down without pausing the video, it still plays. I want to add some script which will do this - onscroll it will autostart video and I will see the first look with poster image.

Also I have one button (named "Scroll to video section") which is under video section, when you click on button it scroll to the video section but it must show video's first look as well - paused and with poster image. I was wondering how can I do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/melbournedesign/cuywdowb/) which has the behaviours you appear to require.

The function below was added to pause the video when any scrolling occurs.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
    jQuery(".video-js")[0].player.pause();
});
```

You can change the function called to .play(); if you want the video to play on scrolling.

Please refer to this discussion [thread](http://help.videojs.com/discussions/suggestions/9-play-and-pause-video-via-jquery) to understand the functions that make the video play and pause.

The code above has been changed to the 3rd code snippet listed below to allow additional functionality.

The function below plays the video  3000ms (3 seconds) after the "Show Video Section" button is clicked.

```
setTimeout(function () {
    jQuery(".video-js")[0].player.play();
}, 3000);
```

The code below resets the video to show the "poster". The current time is stored in order to allow the video to restart from where the user left off.

Please refer to this [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13231844/reset-video-js-plugin-to-initial-state) question for more details.

```
jQuery(document).scroll(function () {
var time = jQuery(".video-js")[0].player.currentTime();     
    jQuery(".video-js")[0].player.pause().currentTime(time).trigger('loadstart');
});
```

The code below was used to change the Js Fiddle to start the video at the beginning on the scroll event.

```
jQuery(".video-js")[0].player.pause().currentTime(0).trigger('loadstart');
```

Comment: yes it pauses when scroll but I must show first look with poster image anf play button over it, it means 'kill' the video when scroll down and clicking on button. How can I kill the video on scroll so it will show how at first time on load? @Pwrcode

Comment: @aidaghazaryan I've changed the JsFiddle to reflect the desired behaviour you appear to want based on your comment. Please look at the JsFiddle to confirm.

Comment: yeah it works fine, just one tiny thing can we make it play at the beginning not where I stopped it? @Pwrcode

Comment: @aidaghazaryan The JsFiddle now plays at the beginning not where it stopped. If this is the desired behaviour could you please select my answer and upvote it. Thanks.